# Making dynamic variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to concatenate the key with my variable in each

```
 $.each(datas, function(key, data) {

      var m.key=data; //something like this           

       });
```

It should print m1="data1" m2="". Dont want to use array. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(datas, function(key, data) {
     m[key]=data;       
});
```

Comment: If this had some explanation of the code, it would be a much better answer and therefore more likely to be upvoted and/or accepted.